# Modules or install profile for scholarly peer review

Tags: 7

Are there any modules or installation profiles available to create a peer-review system, such as used by academic journals and conferences? I've found lots of discussions on Drupal.org but no actively maintained modules.

Update: here is [an example](http://www.x-cd.com/content/demo/abstract-review.cfm) of a commercial system showing the kinds of features I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you give a non-Drupal example that shows the kind of things you are after?

Comment: @chapabu pls see update for an example. this is just the first one I found that shows off features with some level of detail. I am not implying that that system is in any way ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you would like to do, there are two potential approaches.

On the simple end, you have fields on content types that only certain roles can edit.  For example, you can have a field called **vetted** and two roles, **author** and **expert**.  When an **author** makes a new node, **vetted** would get set to some default value, like **not verified**.  Your **expert** users can then read and review the nodes, and sets the **vetted** field as appropriate, say **verified** or **needs further review**.

One the more complex end, you can use workflow.  Two modules that do this are [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) and [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench).  With this, you can set up just about any editorial review process that you want.  Both can also be combined with Drupal actions to occur on state transitions.  Just keep in mind that workflow can be a pain to set up, and often there are real work scenarios that don't always work into rigid workflow rules.

As for existing systems, [Open Atrium](http://openatrium.com/) may potentially fit the bill.  It is more designed for team collaboration, but based on what clients have said, it may work for something more conference oriented.